# Lambda S3 getObject stream to ES ingest pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm using lambda to push PDF files uploaded to S3 over to AWS hosted elasticsearch with the ES ingest attachment plugin.

Some of the PDFs can be large - over 100mb - and it seems like it would be best to stream the files in chunks rather than load the entire file buffer into lambda memory. The s3-lambda-es sample code I've seen all work on json logs which are easy to stream, but I haven't seen anybody working with binary documents for the ingest plugin.

Note: I'm using the elasticssearch-js library with http-aws-es connectionClass to make it work with lambda.

My current code basically works, but it loads the entire pdf before sending to ES. 
Here is the getObject callback:

```
s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      context.fail();
    } else {
      console.log('data: ', data); // successful response
      var attachment = data.Body.toString('base64');
      elasticsearch.index(
        {
          index: 'attachments2',
          pipeline: 'pdf_attachment2',
          type: 'pdf',
          body: {
            data: attachment
          }
        },
        function(error, resp) {
          if (error) {
            console.trace('index error!', error);
          } else {
            console.log('index response', resp);
            context.succeed();
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
```

Is there a better way to stream a single large document to ES?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to stream a single large document to ES?

**Short answer:** no, use `s3.getObject`

**Long answer:** yes, read below

---

First of all, the limitation is Elasticsearch. It simply doesn't expose any streaming API. If you try to [search API docs](https://www.elastic.co/search?q=stream&section=Docs%2FClients%2FJavaScript), you won't even find any mention of streams.

Why? Because Elasticsearch isn't designed for streaming large files into it!

The default limitation is 100MB for request body, which [can be increased to 2GB with tuning](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/general-recommendations.html#maximum-document-size). (same link explains why you should not index such big files). In short, you'll have bad & irrelevant search results, overload ES, eat all RAM and so on.

Moreover, you mentioned you are going to use [ingest attachment plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/ingest-attachment.html), If you proceed to [default configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/using-ingest-attachment.html)  you may notice a default value of `indexed_chars`:

[image]

which means, ES by default prevents you from storing fields larger than 100KB!

Of course, you can override everything, and tune ES as you wish and store 2GB documents in 1 fields. But generally it's not recommended.

The recommended approach is to split big pdf by smaller chunks and index them as separate documents with same `documentId` or whatever. Then you can de-dupe docs by shared `documentId` using [ES fields collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/search-request-collapse.html) (new in ES 5.3, use top hits aggregation in older versions). That what you won't end-up sending 100MB in your Lambda.

**So to sum up:** you cannot stream to ES large text for 1 doc, ES wasn't designed for that. But you can send 100MB text if you wish. AWS Lambda should be fine, memory will be disposed when needed.

Comment: This is great info, thank you. There's very little info available about the ingest plugin and i had naively hoped that it managed the page splitting and all that.

Answer (score -1):

@bscandanavia please share the approach and the code that you used to create pipeline. I am unable to figure out how I have to use ES ingest attachment plugin.

Sorry to post it as answer because I don't have ability to add comments

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, if you have a question i suggest you read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and then create a question linking back to this one for context